# Address Book Contact Synchronization IOS

Tags: ios, addressbook

I am developing the application which requires Address book synchronization whenever the New Contact has been Added.

For example : WhatsApp Like Listing of all the contacts who are available on the App.

What I have done till now : I am fetching the contact numbers from local addressbook and comparing the numbers which are registered with my app at server and storing those numbers back in App.

Problem: Now When New contact has been added , How to compare that contact Number ? I want to only New contact must be compared with server and not all again .

Please help me its just like Whats app contact list .

Comment: Hi , I m doing the same thing and need to know How you are sending all your Contacts to server? are you using any GET/POST webservice and sending contacts in a loop or Uploading all contacts at a time?

Comment: Uploading the contact at a time . And checking at the server and returning back the numbers which are synchronized with contact book

Comment: Hi Krish, thanks for your reply. How you are uploading all the contacts, By storing them in a file and upload the file ?  And how you check online and offline status each time?

Comment: @krish Hi, i'm interested in this too, did you find any solution to sync problem?